# Appcelerator Titanium :: Building on Android Device "Failed to install APK"

Tags: android, adb, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

So I've been using Appcelerator with Android for quite some time now but I think something's changed recently that's causing it to stop installing on my devices. Problem is, I'm not sure where to look for the cause of this (node, adb, titanium cli, titanium studio, titanium sdk, etc.).

```
[INFO] :   Making sure the adb server is running
[INFO] :   Installing apk: /Users/mfogg/sites/my-app/build/android/bin/MyApp.apk
[INFO] :   Installing app on device: SAMSUNG
[TRACE] :  Checking if package manager service is started
[TRACE] :  Package manager has started
[TRACE] :  Executing: /Users/mfogg/Library/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb -s 42f770f563509f53 install -r -d /Users/mfogg/sites/my-app/build/android/bin/MyApp.apk
[ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on "42f770f563509f53"
```

I clearly see it's not installing (ha) but the reason seemed hidden at first. When I copy that command into terminal I get the error

```
Error: Unknown option: -d
```

Does anyone know why Appcelerator is adding that in there (seems like it's trying to pick a device... but it's in the wrong spot)?

**If I remove the -d, it installs via terminal perfectly fine.**

Seems odd, any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`adb install -d` is to allow app version downgrade. It's just your device is too old to support the option.

Comment: Ahh! Interesting. I guess now the question is just finding out why it doesn't detect that my device is too old and not use it :) Baby steps, thanks!